# Laravel - What will technically happen, when i put with() before create or update?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am a little uncertain about some scenarios with use of function with on model before create or update. What you think will happen in next scenarios? It is a little weird and it gave me results without that relations. Why it is allowed? Thanks

```
$item = $vehicle->stkRecords()->with([
'vehicle:id,name',
])->create($request->validated());

return response()->json([
'data' => new StkRecordResource($item)
]);
```

or

```
$item->with([
'vehicle:id,name',
])->update($request->validated());

return response()->json([
'data' => new StkRecordResource($item)
]);
```

I tried to call that apis and there were missing that data.

Comment: It won't break anything, but it won't do anything either. You'd need `$item->load('vehicle')` *after* the update is performed to get it in your API resource.

Comment: Thanks :) 

And what do you think about this?


`
$product->update($request->validated());
            $product->refresh();
            $product->load(
                'category:id,name',
            );

return response()->json([
                'data' => new ProductResource($product),
            ]);
`

Comment: `with` is for *getting* results, not creating/updating results. Like ceejay said: when you return your resource based on the updated/created record, then load in those extra relations. `new StkRecordResource($item)` <<<=== don't do that. By creating or updating a record, you're already getting the object as result: `$updatedItem = $item->update()...` and then you can even do `$updatedItem->refresh()` to get the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 0):

As was also stated in the comments, the `->with()` and `->load()` are used to retrieve relations from the database. By calling `->create()` or `->update()` only the current state of the `StkRecordResource` itself will be persisted in the database and this **will not** persist any changes to any relationships.

In Laravel you must explicitly call the `->create()` or `->update()` on the model you want to persist, for example if you intended to update the `vehicle` relationship you would need to call `->create()` or `->update()` on the `vehicle` itself.

```php
// Obtains the stkRecord along with the related vehicle id and name
$item = $vehicle->stkRecords()->with(['vehicle:id,name']);

// Creates the current model without touching its relationships
$item->create($request->validated());

// Updates the current model without touching its relationships
$item->update($request->validated());


// Creates a vehicle without touching its parent model
$item->vehicle->create($request->validated());

// Updates the vehicle without touching its parent model
$item->vehicle->update($request->validated());
```